# $m + n \sqrt{2}$ is invertible $\iff$ $m^2 - 2n^2 =\pm 1$

Tags: ring-theory, proof-explanation

I'm having trouble proving that, for $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, the existence of a multiplicative inverse for $m + n \sqrt{2}$ implies that $m^2 - 2n^2 = \pm 1$.

The first step, I believe, is to solve for the inverse, which is clearly $\frac{1}{m + n\sqrt{2}}$, provided that $m  +n \sqrt{2}$, as $m + n \sqrt{2}$ would otherwise not be invertible. From here,  I'm unsure on how to piece together this proof. I read through some hints on another answer on here, so it seems that a plausible step is to use the fact that $m^2 - 2n^2$ is a difference of squares and factors into $(m - \sqrt{2} n)(m + \sqrt{2}n)$. One of these factors is invertible, but we don't have any information on whether it's conjugate is, or ability to equate the product with, say, $1$ or $-1$, so I can't quite figure out how to get there.

In the opposite direction, the first step seems to be  factoring into $(m + n \sqrt{2})(m - n \sqrt{2}) = \pm 1$. If this product is equal to $1$, then, $m - n \sqrt{2}$ is clearly the inverse of $m + n \sqrt{2}$, as we end up with a product of $1$. If not, we could scale both sides by $-1$, which should give us the same inverse.

Any helpful thoughts and hint swould be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're working over $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$?

Comment: Do you know the *norm* of a quadratic integer, and its multiplicative property?

Comment: To elaborate on @ertl's comment:  the statement you're trying to prove is only true if by "multiplicative inverse" you mean "multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$".  The issue is whether the reciprocal (which of course makes sense as a real number as long as $m + n \sqrt 2 \neq 0$) actually has the form $a + b \sqrt 2$ for $a, b \in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, the only candidate for the inverse is clearly $\frac1{m+n\sqrt{2}}$.

We have

$$\frac1{m+n\sqrt{2}} = \frac{m-n\sqrt{2}}{m^2-2n^2} = \frac{m}{m^2-2n^2} + \frac{-n}{m^2-2n^2}\sqrt{2}$$

This is an element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ if and only if both $\frac{m}{m^2-2n^2}$ and $\frac{-n}{m^2-2n^2}$ are in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $d = \gcd(m,n)$. Assume that $m^2-2n^2 \mid m$ and $m^2-2n^2 \mid n$. Then also $m^2-2n^2 \mid d$. On the other hand, $d \mid m$ and $d \mid n$ so $d^2 \mid m^2-2n^2$. Therefore $d^2 \mid d$ so $d = 1$.

Therefore if $\frac{m}{m^2-2n^2}, \frac{-n}{m^2-2n^2} \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $m^2-2n^2$ divides $d = 1$ so we conclude $m^2-2n^2 = \pm 1$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you also have to show that it's not the case that you have both $(m^2-2n^2)|m$ and $(m^2-2n^2)|n$; for instance, $\gcd(m,n)=1$ is enough to guarantee this.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki True, this only works if $\gcd(m,n) = 1$. I'm not entirely sure how to fix this without introducing the norm.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that there's a clean supplemental argument that you must have $\gcd(m,n)=1$: suppose $\gcd(m,n)=d\neq 1$. Then $d|m$ so $d^2|m^2$; likewise $d^2|n^2$.  But then $d^2|(m^2-2n^2)$, and since (by hypothesis) $(m^2-2n^2)|m$ and $(m^2-2n^2)|n$, $d^2|m$ and $d^2|n$, contradiction the assertion

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks a lot, I have added it in the answer.

Comment: I think this whole argument looks great, BTW - all three answers (as of right now) are very solid but this is more first-principles than the others; all that's needed to understand it is rationalizing denominators and basic divisibility.

Answer (score 5):

Introduce the map $\nu :A=\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]\to \mathbb Z$ such that $\nu(a+b\sqrt 2) = a^2-2b^2$, let us call this the *norm map*. Then I claim that $\nu$ is *multiplicative* (exercise, and the most important part of all this proof, really!). Now suppose that $x$ is invertible in $A$, so there is $y$ such that $xy=1$. Applying $\nu$, we see that $\nu(x)$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z$. Since the units in this ring are $1$ and $-1$, we have shown that

> If $x$ is a unit in $A$, then $\nu(x)$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z$, i.e. $\pm 1$.

Now you want to prove the converse of the above. Hence assume that the norm is a unit. If $x=a+b\sqrt 2$, let $\bar x=a-b\sqrt 2$, the *conjugate* of $x$. Then $x\bar x=\nu(x)$, and since $\nu(x)$ is $\pm 1$, we see that the inverse of $x$ is simply $\nu(x) \bar x$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a different take.

The ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ is isomorphic to a subring of $M_2(\mathbb Z)$, the ring of $2 \times 2$ integer matrices:
$$
\phi: m + n \sqrt 2 \mapsto \pmatrix{ m & 2n \\ n & m }
$$
Then, $m + n \sqrt 2$ is invertible iff $\phi(m + n \sqrt 2)$ is invertible iff $\det\phi(m + n \sqrt 2)$ is invertible iff $\det\phi(m + n \sqrt 2)=\pm 1$.

The isomorphism $\phi$ comes from the maps $\mu : x \mapsto x (m + n \sqrt 2)$ in the $\mathbb Z$-basis $1,\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Of course this is 'basically' the norm argument in disguise, but that doesn't make it any less excellent. Very neat!